# Ballerina Lang - API Key Authentication using Request/ResponseFilter

Tags: ballerina

I am looking for an example of API Key Authentication using Request/ResponseFilter in Ballerina lang. Any recommendations?

Comment: Just to clarify, can you please let me know what is the API that you are trying to authenticate with? Else what is its authentication protocol?

Comment: SendGrid API - https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

You can use OAuth2 direct config which configures the `Authorization` header value as `Bearer <token>`. Please refer to API docs [1] and Ballerina by exampl [2] for more information.

A sample code to call SendGrid API is as follows:

```
oauth2:OutboundOAuth2Provider oauth2Provider = new ({
    accessToken: "Your.API.Key-HERE"
});
http:BearerAuthHandler oauth2Handler = new (oauth2Provider);

http:Client clientEP = new ("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/resource", {
    auth: {
        authHandler: oauth2Handler
    },
    secureSocket: {
        trustStore: {
            path: "/path/to/truststore.p12",
            password: "ballerina"
        }
    }
});
```

[1] https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/oauth2/records/DirectTokenConfig.html

[2] https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/secured-client-with-oauth2.html